# Glassfish 4, simple example in CDI fails with WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, glassfish, cdi

I am a very newbie in CDI. This is my FIRST example and I am trying to run it. Having searched the internet I wrote the following code:
Class that I want to be injected

```
public class Temp {

public Temp(){

}

public String getMe(){
    return "something";
}
}
```

Servlet

```
@WebServlet(name = "NewServlet", urlPatterns = {"/NewServlet"})
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Inject
public Temp temp;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1> Here it is"+temp.getMe()+ "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
    }
}
...
```

But I have to following error in glassfish 4:

> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied
>   dependencies for type [Temp] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection
>   point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private
>   xxx.example.NewServlet.temp]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add beans.xml in WEB-INF?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either no `beans.xml` exists within `WEB-INF` or the file requires changing `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"` to `bean-discovery-mode="all"`.

---

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
  bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

#### Explanation

The recommended value "`annotated`" only recognizes annotated `CDI` managed beans. Beans without any annotation are ignored. As your `Temp` class is not `CDI` bean, so recommendation is not applicable in your case.

#### Using bean-discovery-mode="annotated"

To work with `annotated`, annotate the class with @RequestScoped:

```
// Import only this RequestScoped
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@RequestScoped
public class Temp {

    public Temp() { }

    public String getMe() {
        return "something";
    }
}
```

This `RequestScoped` will convert your `Temp` class to `CDI` bean and will be work with  `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"`.

Answer (score 3):

At me worked with this command:

```
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.cdi-service.enable-implicit-cdi=false
```

So disable the enable-implicit-cdi worked for me.

Comment: Ok, so this is from terminal ?

Comment: Or can this be passed as an argument?

Comment: When I try this, I get "NCLS-ADMIN-00010
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Tue Apr 03 18:09:20 EDT 2018
Command set failed."  But I have checked all my certs in cacerts.jks and keystore.jks, and none of them are expired.  Help?