# CDI - what is the correct bean.xml format?

Tags: java, glassfish, cdi, jboss-weld

I have a question about the correct format and usage of the bean.xml file. In my projects I typically used this content for my bean.xml files (no explizit bean declaration used):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

This works well in WildFly 8 and 9. But I have deployment issues in GlassFish 4. In the question: [Glassfish 4, simple example in CDI fails with WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899920/glassfish-4-simple-example-in-cdi-fails-with-weld-001408-unsatisfied-dependenci) I wrote about an alternative format:

```
<beans
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
          bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

There a different namespaces used. And GlassFish4 seems to care about that.

What is the correct format of an empty bean.xml File used for JEE7 ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Correct empty `beans.xml` can be **totally empty** file, really ;-)

But when you want to add some content, please notice that most of the XML deployment descriptor namespaces have been updated in Java EE 7. This [post describes](http://antoniogoncalves.org/2013/06/04/java-ee-7-deployment-descriptors/) the details. Also `bean-discovery-mode` has been added.

BTW: Sample `beans.xml` which I'm using right now looks like:

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.2" bean-discovery-mode="annotated">

    <!-- some content -->
</beans>
```

You may notice the usage of `version="1.2"` attribute - you can freely set it to `1.1`. It just serves as a reminder to the reader that project is using CDI 1.2 (which in fact is just a *Maintenance release* of the **CDI 1.1** Specification).

Comment: stricly speaking, IMHO, that is not totally empty: there a single bit of information in the bean-discovery-mode="annotated" attribute. I guess they could have done better getting rid of it, and defaulting to "all", IMHO again.