# management sessions JSF 2.3 CDI

Tags: spring, jsf, cdi, tomcat8, myfaces

Having recently upgraded to `JSF 2.3` from `2.2`, I noticed that `@ManagedBean` was deprecated, and after some research found that I should be using `CDI-2.0` managed beans and the `@Named` annotation.
I also migrated `@javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` to `@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`.

However i noticed that my beans are created on the server's startup!

I login with an user 'X' and i change an attribute in my bean. after that i login with another browser and i expect to find null in my attribute but i have found the last update by the user 'X' in the other browser.

I'm using myFaces 2.3, omnifaces 3.1, i also installed CDI in my tomcat. i have referenced to some blogs and some responses stackoverflow like :

http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html

[Migrate JSF managed beans to CDI managed beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155440/migrate-jsf-managed-beans-to-cdi-managed-beans)

Here are my principal files :

beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

pom.xml:

```
.....
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces.all.themes}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.omnifaces/omnifaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bootsfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootsfaces</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Oracle jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
.....

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: "I also migrated `@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` to `@javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped`" -> you should be going the other way around. CDI version is `javax.entrerprise.context.SessionScoped` so that's the one you want to be using.

Comment: @Siliarus: Was most likely a typo since it is corrected

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942876/cdi-what-is-the-correct-bean-xml-format, you seem to have old beans.xml definition (if you need one at all)

Comment: I'm using also Spring so i think the problem is about CDI + Spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and i implemented a solution, so i want to share it with you.
The problem was the component-scan of spring framework and here my solution :

XML:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example">  
    <context:exclude-filter type="aspectj" expression="com.example.beans.*" />  
</context:component-scan>
```

Annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example" },
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASPECTJ, pattern = "com.example.beans.*"))
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The second problem is about spring's bean injection into CDI bean so i create a bridge between Spring and CDI.

I have to create a new annotation like this :

```
@Qualifier
@Inherited
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ FIELD, TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER })
public @interface SpringBean {

    String value() default "";
}
```

and a Producer :

```
@SessionScoped
public class CdiBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -44416514616012281L;

    @Produces
    public PropertyResourceBundle getBundle() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        return context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{msg}", PropertyResourceBundle.class);
    }

    @Produces
    @SpringBean("example")
    public Example example(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return (Example) findBean(injectionPoint);
    }


    protected Object findBean(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        Annotated annotated = injectionPoint.getAnnotated();
        SpringBean springBeanAnnotation = annotated.getAnnotation(SpringBean.class);
        ServletContext ctx = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();

        String name = springBeanAnnotation.value();

        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(name))
            return WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(ctx).getBean(name);
        else 
            throw new NoSuchBeanDefinitionException(name, "not found in Context");

    }
}
```

And i inject it into my bean like that :

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ExampleBean extends AbstractManagedBean  implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ExampleBean.class);

    @Inject
    @SpringBean("example")
    protected transient Example example;

    @Inject
    protected transient PropertyResourceBundle bundle;

..................

}
```

thank!

Comment: Thanks for sharing... But effectively, the tagging and çode' was both sort of off... The fact that you use spring is waaaay more important than that you use Tomcat (or JSF) and you added those tags but not a spring one (please correct that in the question). And in the 'dependencies' Spring was also 'ommitted'. Please next time pay way more attention to things like this. Create a [mcve]. Start removing things untill you find a narrowed down cause (or a solution). Saves you time posting an unclear question and us chasing a 'ghost' ;-). But great you found a solution.